# CiviContribute "Held For Review"

Tags: civicontribute, authorize.net

We received a donation through our website via CiviContribute. In our payment gateway (Authorize.net), we had certain countries blocked from making online donations due to previous fraudulent activity. This donor happened to be from one of these blocked countries, so initially her transaction was denied. She called us, we told her to try her donation again and we "Held it for Review" in Authorize.net. Then, we approved the donation.

The transaction went through Authorize.net successfully, however, I can't find any record of her donation in CiviCRM. Can someone tell me where her donation is being stored? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

While researching another issue I stumbled across this on JIRA: https://issues.civicrm.org/jira/browse/CRM-17779 - so as of 4.7.9, it looks as if you will be able to update the pending contribution to completed (haven't tested, but you should test both online and offline contributions to see what happens).

Kind regards,
Tamar

Comment: This is the correct answer.  My client funded this feature specifically to handle Authorize.Net payments held for fraud detection.

Answer (score 0):

In my experience, I have seen that contributions that are held for review and then manually approved do not trigger the IPN to send a message back to Civi to create a contribution and that those contributions need to be recorded manually in Civi to match what is reflected on authorize.net. But before you do that, just in case, did you try searching for the contribution by date, amount or some other generic criteria without reference to a contact name to make sure that the contribution didn't end up on a new contact record?

Hope this helps,
Tamar